# Eager Loading in ASP MVC returns null from navigation property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have an ASP MVC 5 Web application with code first migrations enabled. I have two tables/classes named Post.cs and PostSubject.cs.

**Post.cs**

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Title is required")]
    [MaxLength(255,ErrorMessage="Title too long")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1023,ErrorMessage="Description too long")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public PostSubject PostSubject { get; set; }


    [Display(Name="Stream")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Choose a Stream")]
    public int PostSubjectId { get; set; }


    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

**PostSubject.cs**

```
public class PostSubject
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to load all the Posts along with their PostSubjects in the index view.

**Index Action**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var contributions =_context.Posts.Include(m=>m.PostSubject).ToList();
   return View(contributions);
}
```

**Index Html**

```html
@model IEnumerable<Cluster_University.Models.Post>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Descripttion</td>
        <td>Subject</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var posts in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@posts.Title</td>
            <td>@posts.Description</td>
            <td>@posts.PostSubject.SubjectName</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Problem: I have a null reference error at @Posts.PostSubject.SubjectName

Please make me understand the problem in my code.

Comment: Have you checked PostSubject has value? It seems there is no reference declared in the model between Post and PostSubject.

Comment: You have a PostSubject property, but did you [configure the relation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx#Configuring/Mapping%20Relationships)?

Comment: I appreciate your engagement with the post. But there is a navigation property of type PostSubject in Post.cs. So the two are related to each other.

Comment: To debug EF issues, [log the SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx) and check the generated SQL against the database.

Comment: will there be only 1 `PostSubject` per `Post` or there can be multiple `PostSubject` per `Post`?

Comment: @Sumitraj There can be only one subject of a post.